# CascadeType.ALL not deleting Children of Children

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I got the following structure:

**SimpleSectionConfig.java**

This Entity contains

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "layout", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<SimpleSection> sections;
```

**SimpleSection.java**

The SimpleSection Entity then contains

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "section", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Seat> seats;
```

When I delete by Id it seems like it tries to delete the sections which makes sense because of CascadeType.ALL.

However there is also CascadeType.ALL for the attribute seats but the seats do not get removed

I get the following Exception:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Aktualisieren oder Löschen in Tabelle »simple_section« verletzt Fremdschlüssel-Constraint »fk_seat_section« von Tabelle »seat«
> Detail: Auf Schlüssel (id)=(1) wird noch aus Tabelle »seat« verwiesen.

Which translates to:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Refreshing or Removal in Table »simple_section« hurt foreign key constraint »fk_seat_section«  of Table »seat«
> Detail: To Key(id)=(1) is still pointed from table »seat«

How can I get the seats removed as well?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Postgres @Diego Borba